# Copying Files into AppData\Roaming after/before building

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I am currently using the built in post-build event to move files to a temporary directory:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)RequiredItems/*" "C:\Users\Jcras\Documents\temp"
```

However I would like to move these to the users Roaming AppData dynamically.

I was unable to get the following code to work:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)RequiredItems/*" "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Elysium\"
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)RequiredItems/*" "%AppData%/Roaming/Elysium/"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Edit:

The following works:

```
xcopy /s /y "$(ProjectDir)RequiredItems\*" "C:\Users\Jcras\Documents\temp\"
xcopy /s /y "$(ProjectDir)RequiredItems\*" "C:\Users\Jcras\AppData\Roaming\Elysium\"
```

Comment: Just for the record, `%AppData%` already refers to `Roaming`, so `%AppData%/Roaming/Elysium` would actually expand to `%UserProfile%/AppData/Roaming/Roaming/Elysium`, which I imagine is not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to [Nacimota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029145/nacimota) I was able to generate the solution:

```
xcopy /s /y "$(ProjectDir)RequiredItems\*" "%AppData%\Elysium\"
```

It looks as though I was mistaken and was simply placing the data in Roaming\Roaming*

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help also (took me some time to figure):

```
...
    <Target Name="MyDistClean" AfterTargets="Clean">
        <ItemGroup>
            <DistDir Include="$(APPDATA)\MyApp\Configuration\" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Message Text="Deleting @(DistDir)" Importance="high" />
        <RemoveDir Directories="@(DistDir)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: can't bold in the code, so notice the **$(APPDATA)**